# Objectify entity

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

Can I pass an objectify entity (i.e class annotated by `@Entity`) to a function accepting `com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Java is a typed language.  You can only pass subclasses of com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity to a function which accepts com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity.  Anything else won't compile.

Comment: Right that's what I expect to happen too, however, is there anyway for an Objectify entity to have a functionality like the GAE Entity which we can do "getProperty"?

Comment: BTW, I was not able to give my point, my question should have been if objectify entity is a type datastore entity...

Answer (score 0):

No, the entity annotation doesn't change the type of the object. There is no "getProperty" in objectify but you could certainly use reflection or commons BeanUtils to do a similar thing.